# Javascript Map taking several minutes to set 7k keys

Tags: javascript

I have around 7k database entries I want to set into a map. I loop through the data fetched from the db and set it into the map. However, it takes a very long time (around 3 minutes), to set these keys. Is there a better way to do it rather than just looping over the entries and setting them one by one? I'm using a map for cache and run a task every minute for this cache to be updated, but the map itself takes 3 minutes for all the keys to be set.

I'm setting an object as the value, like so:

```js
const data = await fetchDataFromDb();

for (const element of data) cache.set(element.id, element)
```

`cache` here is a class extending map (which makes no changes to set method), having some custom methods.

[image: cache update]

Comment: Have you checked the mapping is slow, and not fetching? Please show all the relevant code (a short example of `data`, `cache.set` method and everything else which is participating to the mapping).

Comment: I'm pretty sure only the mapping is slow, yeah. The average response time from the db is around 150-200ms. There is not much code, apart from what I showed above. I just fetch data from db, and set the data into the cache by looping over it, that is it. Data is an array of objects.

Comment: I'm using redis as a database, in the example above, I fetch the data from the db like so: (using redis-om for node)

```javascript
console.log(`Updating cache...`);
const data = await Repository.search().all(); // returns all the entries in the index
for const (element of data) cache.set(element.id, element)
console.log(`Updated cache`);
```
The code above is of a cron job, which runs every minute.

This is the structure of the object: 

```
{
id: 'some string',
track: 'something',
// ... other properties
}
```

Comment: No repro, a code based on the given information maps 7K data within 2 msecs.

Comment: What data are you setting? Are they *huge*?

Comment: `like so:` - place all relevant code **in the question**, where you can make it readable